# Which is the optimal way to add lots of data to an existing database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, data-migration, rake-task

I have a database with a table that consists of 65k+ entries, which is used in my production Rails app, and I want to add some 40k+ more rows from a CSV file I have, ensuring that the data gets into:
1) db on my development machine,
2) db on the production server,
3) db on my team members' machines.

What approach should I choose? A rake task for populating the table? A migration?

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is going to depend entirely on the data you're importing.  If you're only ever going to import it once, and never touch it again, a migration is the right way to go.  If you intend to update the CSV and replace / append the data in the database, you probably will want to consider a rake task.